# External CSS file not working properly

Tags: html, css

My CSS style sheet header is not working. It works best in internal stylesheet or embedded stylesheet, but did not work when its code in external stylesheet. Only the header class did not wok but other code working best.

```css
        .header1{
            background-color: brown ;
            padding: 20px;
            background-image: url("pics/saqib.png");
        }
        #pic{
            float: right;
        }
        ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        li {
                float:left;
                background-color: #333;
                border-top-left-radius: 35%;
                border-top-right-radius: 35%;
                margin-left:2px;
            }

        li a {
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
        li a:hover {
                background-color: green;
        }
        .navbar{
            padding: 20px;
            margin-top: 150px;
        }
        /* End nav bar */
        .skin{
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .table {
            margin-top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .table .sidebar{
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            width: 20%;
        }
        .footer{
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 20px;
            padding: 100px;
        }
        .left{
            float: left;
            display: block;
            width: 40%;
            color: gray;
            border-right: 2px solid white;
            border-color: gray;
            padding-right: 70px;
        }
        .right{
            float: right;
            display: block;
            width: 40%;
            color: gray;
        }
        pre a{
            font-family: helvatic, sanshrif;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: white;
        }
        pre a:hover{
            color: green;

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>My Page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mypage.css"/>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
            <header class="header">
                <div id="pic"> <img src="pics/saqib.png"/></div>
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </header>
            <div class="skin">
                <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sidebar">
                                    This is sidebar
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 50px;">
                                <h1>My First Website</h1>
                                <p> A collection of all steps to complete a process in known as Transaction. DBMS  should support transaction. It must ensure that all steps in a transaction are executed successfully or none of them is executed. It facility ensures that the database is always in consistent state even if a transaction fails due to some problem such as system crash or power failure etc.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <footer class="footer">
                                    <div class="left">
                                        <pre><a href="#">Home</a>  |  <a href="#">Software</a>  |  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>  |  <a href="#">About us</a></pre>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="right">
                                        The most important function of DBMS 
                                        is data processing. It includes creation,
                                        storage and arrangements of data in database.
                                    </div>
                                </footer>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change in  either one place to make it work:

In HTML:

```
<header class="header">
```

to:

```
<header class="header1">
```

or in CSS:

```css
.header1 {
    background-color: brown;
    padding: 20px;
    background-image: url("pics/saqib.png");
}
```

to:

```css
.header {
    background-color: brown;
    padding: 20px;
    background-image: url("pics/saqib.png");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your stylesheet defines a `.header1` class but your HTML is looking for `header`. Make those the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
.header{
            background-color: brown ;
            padding: 20px;
            background-image: url("pics/saqib.png");
        }
```